# Prime number identification and squaring

Tags: java, primes

I was asked to write code for the following Question,

> Find the prime numbers in an array of given numbers and print the sum
>   of squares of the prime numbers found.

And this was my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class primenumber2
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] int1  = {2,3,4,6,11,13,17,99};

        int square=0;
        int result=0;

        boolean isprime = true;

        for(int i=0;i<int1.length;i++)
        {   
            int temp=int1[i];
            for(int j=1;j<i;j++)
            {

                if(temp%j==0)
                {
                    isprime = false;

                }
                else
                    isprime = true;


            }
            if(isprime)
                {   
                    System.out.println(temp);
                    square = temp*temp;
                    result = result+square; 
                }



        }

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that every number that ends with 9,gets added as a prime,i couldn't find out why.

Can someone help me with this? and also if ,possible a better way to solve this problem just using the basic functions and classes.

Comment: You probably don't want to set `isprime` to true inside your `for j` loop. What your saying there is "if `j` is not a factor of `temp`, then `temp` is prime". That's faulty logic. It's prime if _none_ of the numbers you checked is a factor, not if the _last_ number you checked is not a factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 problems

- you start `for-loop` from `1`
- your check until `j<i` which is the index of the first loop.

```
for(int j=1;j<i;j++)
//           ↑ why limit this loop at index of the outer loop? 
//        ↑ start at 1 (WRONG!)
```

To check primes, you must start with `number % 2` until `number % number - 1`

```
for(int j=2;j<temp;j++)
```

---

But in order to clarify and save iterations, I would make a method to check primes like this:

```
private static boolean isPrime(int toCheck) {
    for (int i = 2; i < toCheck; i++) {
        // stop iterating if you know number is even
        if (toCheck % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] int1 = { 2, 3, 4, 6, 11, 13, 17, 99 };

    int square = 0;
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < int1.length; i++) {
        if (isPrime(int1[i])) {
            System.out.println(int1[i]);
            square = int1[i] * int1[i];
            result += square;
        }

    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2
3
11
13
17
592
```

which seems correct

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to check until `toCheck/2` ?

Comment: @Fildor it's actually the square root of `toCheck`, rounded down.

Comment: How in the world does this answer deserve a downvote?

Comment: Revenge downvoting ... gotta love it. Really mature move. Doing it to a guy with 16k+ Rep ... yeah ...

Comment: it happens sometimes, but I don't care about, I just wanted Zia to correct the error and give an ugly but correct solution to OP.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282660/prime-number-identification-and-squaring/40282945#comment67824146_40282945

Comment: @gg_49 glad to help... as this is your first question, kindly check [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to learn how to mark your question as solved in StackOverflow